# Accessing a file through System.IO while a folder in the path is a shortcut

Tags: c#, windows-8, 64-bit, windows-server-2008

I have to create a file and the path to the file contains a folder that is actually a shortcut.

Example:

`D:\SQL Backups\LocumsExcite_04-Sep-2013 16-36-59-135.bak`

The `SQL Backups` folder is a shortcut in `D:` drive. The shortcut takes us to `C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\SQL Backups\` folder

I looked at the Shell examples everywhere but its not working for me.

```
public static string GetShortcutTarget(string shortcutFilename)
    {
        string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(shortcutFilename);
        string filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(shortcutFilename);

        Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.ShellClass();
        Shell32.Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(pathOnly);
        Shell32.FolderItem folderItem = folder.ParseName(filenameOnly);

        if (folderItem != null)
        {
            if (folderItem.IsLink)
            {
                Shell32.ShellLinkObject link = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)folderItem.GetLink;
                return link.Path;
            }
            return shortcutFilename;
        }
        return "";  // not found
    }
```

The line `shell.NameSpace(pathOnly);` always return a null. Any suggestions?